# how can I sync second screen and make it clickable?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-displaymanager, android-presentation

I am making an app for a dual display device for 1:1, face to face consulting.

Basically, the secondary screen is not clickable. So, what I need to do is implementing a presentation.

But some activities are sharable screen. So, it must be clickable in both screens. By default, the second screen is not clickable, but the second monitor displays the same screen. For making it clickable, I need to implement the presentation class for it. However, it will take a lot of times to implement it. So, Is there any simpler way to share the second screen and clickable?

(In presentation, the views are clickable/scrollable/etc)

Comment: "In presentation, the views are clickable/scrollable/etc" -- what evidence do you have that `Presentation` supports input from an external display?

Comment: I tested it out and the secondary screen's button is clickable(the second monitor is touch screen). So, I guess it behaves a dialog. Why? @CommonsWare

Comment: Partly, my concern was whether the hardware would support it. Partly, my concern was whether `Presentation` was written with an eye towards supporting it. `Presentation` came out ~7 years ago, back when our only external display options (HDMI, Miracast, etc.) would not have supported touch input. I wasn't sure, therefore, if they set up `Presentation` to actually support it, once we started getting connectivity options where it might be practical.

Comment: In terms of your question... if the device is running Android 8.0+, you can launch an activity on the external display, using only some additional setup in the `startActivity()` call.

Comment: @CommonsWare What kind of set up for startActivity?

Comment: Sadly, The OS is 7.1.1...

Comment: You can use [`ActivityOptions`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ActivityOptions#setLaunchDisplayId(int)) to declare what display ID to use to display the activity, then have it create a `Bundle` to pass along in the `startActivity()` call. However, that is moot since your device is not running Android 8.0+. `Presentation` is the simplest option for you.

Comment: @CommonsWare Well, the activity does a lot of work and complicated, so, I guess if there's a way to implement the same method like this[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971442/android-o-launch-on-secondary-display] then, it would be nicer.

Comment: Upgrade your device to Android 8.0.

Comment: Sorry, It shouldn't. The OS not pure Android OS. But the manufacturer added many features and I need them. @CommonsWare

Comment: Talk to the manufacturer about upgrading its OS to be based on Android 8.0 or higher. For your current situation, `Presentation` is the simplest option for you.